# perform operations on a data frame based on a factors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm having a hard time to describe this so it's best explained with an example (as can probably be seen from the poor question title).

Using dplyr I have the result of a `group_by` and `summarize` I have a data frame that I want to do some further manipulation on by factor.

As an example, here's a data frame that looks like the result of my dplyr operations:

```
> df <- data.frame(run=as.factor(c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3))),
             group=as.factor(rep(c("a","b","c"),2)),
             sum=c(1,8,34,2,7,33))
> df
  run group sum
1   1     a   1
2   1     b   8
3   1     c  34
4   2     a   2
5   2     b   7
6   2     c  33
```

I want to divide `sum` by a value that depends on `run`.   For example, if I have:

```
> total <- data.frame(run=as.factor(c(1,2)),
                      total=c(45,47))
> total
  run total
1   1    45
2   2    47
```

Then my final data frame will look like this:

```
> df
  run group sum percent
1   1     a   1    1/45
2   1     b   8    8/45
3   1     c  34   34/45
4   2     a   2    2/47
5   2     b   7    7/47
6   2     c  33   33/47
```

Where I manually inserted the fraction in the `percent` column by hand to show the operation I want to do.

I know there is probably some dplyr way to do this with `mutate` but I can't seem to figure it out right now. How would this be accomplished?

Comment: df$percent <- df$sum/total[df$run,'total']

Comment: Very elegant HubertL.  If you post as an answer I will accept.  This is even simpler than what I envisioned with `mutate` (although that does work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(In base R)

You can use `total` as a look-up table where you get a total for each run of `df` :

```
total[df$run,'total']
[1] 45 45 45 47 47 47
```

And you simply use it to divide the sum and assign the result to a new column:

```
df$percent <- df$sum / total[df$run,'total']

  run group sum    percent
1   1     a   1 0.02222222
2   1     b   8 0.17777778
3   1     c  34 0.75555556
4   2     a   2 0.04255319
5   2     b   7 0.14893617
6   2     c  33 0.70212766
```

Answer (score 1):

If your "run" values are 1,2...n then this will work

```
divisor <- c(45,47) # c(45,47,...up to n divisors)
df$percent <- df$sum/divisor[df$run]
```

Answer (score 0):

first you want to merge in the total values into your df:

```
df2 <- merge(df, total, by = "run")
```

then you can call mutate:

```
df2 %<>% mutate(percent = sum / total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to `data.table` in-place, then merge and add new column, again in-place:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[total, on = 'run', percent := sum/total]
df
#   run group sum    percent
#1:   1     a   1 0.02222222
#2:   1     b   8 0.17777778
#3:   1     c  34 0.75555556
#4:   2     a   2 0.04255319
#5:   2     b   7 0.14893617
#6:   2     c  33 0.70212766
```